# Testing Comma separated values in a field, at a time , in karate

Tags: api, automation, karate, payload

I am testing an email API
In the the payload, I have to pass multiple values in the "to" field.
This essentially means, I need to test the functionality of sending an email to more than one recipient in Karate framework.
Is it possible to read multiple values at a time for a field in Karate?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing much to do with Karate, but since Karate supports JS:

```
* def before = 'foo,bar,baz'
* def after = before.split(',')
* match after == ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```